# .html() method is not changing the div content

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Hello guys need some help.
I have a ajax code like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ajaxLoadPage").click(function(){
        var page=$(this).attr('id');
        alert(page);
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:"/SMS/jsp/"+page+".do",
            async:false,
            dataType:"html",
            cache:false,
            success:function(result){
                $('#main-content').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
}),
```

which is successfully returning the 'result' from the server, but when I'm trying to overwrite the div `#main-content` with result like

```
$('#main-content').html(result);
```

for a few fraction of second the `div#main-content` is get replaced/overwrite with 'result' but after this the `div#main-content` is automatically loading the previous/old content?

Please help me I'm exactly getting why this error is occurring.

Comment: Check if the id is duplicate. If not, add complete HTML

Comment: Sounds like your page is reloaded in some way... Aren't you submiting a form? What `result` looks like? And FYI, `async: false` is a no go

Comment: What does `console.log(result)` say?

Comment: is `ajaxLoadPage` a submit/anchor ?

Comment: if `.ajaxLoadPage` is a link/button (like @AnoopJoshi said), the page gets reloaded. Add the parameter `e` to the function call (`.click(function(e){`) and in the first line of the function, add `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Please pick one of the answers as accepted. It is rude to ask a question here and then give not credit to the people that came to help you.

Comment: Seriously, pick one of the answers as accepted already. You have been reminded three times now, are you being rude on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You've said:

```
async:false
```

Which means the JavaScript will block everything else that is happening on the page.

> for a few fraction of second the div#main-content is get replaced/overwrite with 'result' but after this the div#main-content is automatically loading the previous/old content?

That means that you are triggering the JavaScript by doing something that naturally loads a new page. Probably clicking on a link or submitting a form.

If you didn't have `async:false`, it would have just reloaded the page without waiting for the JS to run.

---

To fix this properly:

Write [quality HTML and enhance it with JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Set up the link that triggers the JS so it does the right thing [when JS fails](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html). (NB: You should get this to return a complete HTML document).

```
<a href="/SMS/jsp/something.do">...</a>
```

Then you can use the href in the JavaScript.

```
url: $(this).attr('href'),
```

Make sure you prevent the default behaviour of the link when JS is available:

```
$(".ajaxLoadPage").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

You'll need to adapt `$('#main-content').html(result);` so it filters out the content you aren't updating (such as main navigation).

And don't block the browser from getting on with other stuff while waiting for the data from the server (remove `async:false,`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery function specifically for this use case. It's called `.load()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)).

```
$(function() {
    $(".ajaxLoadPage").click(function () {
        $('#main-content').load("/SMS/jsp/" + this.id + ".do");
    });
});
```

Even if you don't want to use this function, your approach is still more complicated than it has to be:

```
$(function() {
    $(".ajaxLoadPage").click(function () {
        $.get("/SMS/jsp/" + this.id + ".do").done(function (result) {
            $('#main-content').html(result);
        });
    });
});
```

Notes:

- There is not a single reason to use synchronous Ajax requests. Ever.
- Send proper HTTP caching headers from the server and you don't need to influence caching behavior at the client. This is always preferable.
- There is no need to use `$.ajax()` when `$.get()` does the job just as well.
- `$(this).attr('id')` is a very verbose way of saying `this.id`.

Comment: Ya, but how would this fixes OP's issue? `event.preventDefault();` sounds like what is missing

Comment: @A.Wolff It probably doesn't, because the OP's issue does not appear to be in the sample code he shows. (If `.ajaxLoadPage` is an `<a>`, then yes. That, or something like `href="#"`).

Comment: @ Tomalak, Hi buddy very very thanks, your suggestion is perfectly working for me. Once again very very thanks.

Comment: @SaaDAhmed If your question has been solved, please upvote the helpful answers and pick one of them as accepted.

Comment: @Tomalak Hi buddy, first of all I apologies that I didn't made up vote to your answer, But the actual reason is, 1- I'm very new to stackoverflow, and 2- is I tried to up vote u at the moment when u asked me first time, but the problem is while doing up voting to your post I'm getting the massage like this "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score". This the reason that is not allowing me to up vote your answer. Now you only suggest me how to earn total 15 reputation.

Comment: I didnt say you have to upvote *my* answer (you will get the required reputation to vote in time). But at least mark one of them accepted. Not necessarily mine either, but the one that helped you the most. A thread on this site remains open until this happens,  and unless your question is not solved, there is no reason to keep it open.

Answer (score 0):

The fallowing comment has helped me to solve my issue
**`(If .ajaxLoadPage is an <a>, then yes. That, or something like href="#")`** 
Given by @Tomalak